# Is there a more exact quote/translation of what Orban said recently about aid to Ukraine?

Tags: european-union, ukraine, reference-request, foreign-aid, hungary

RFERL [has it as](https://www.rferl.org/a/hungary-orban-eu-ukraine-strategy-failed/32656216.html)

> Speaking in Brussels on the sidelines of the EU summit where discussion was focused on support for Ukraine, Orban said there was a “big battle” over the matter and added that **he saw no reason for Hungary to send its taxpayers’ money to support Kyiv**, which has been battling to repel invading Russian troops sent by Putin since February 2022. [...]
>
> Orban said the biggest problem was that the Brussels strategy to send money and military aid to Ukraine to help its fight against Russia “has failed”.

Did Orban really exclude *any* kind of financial aid to Ukraine? Is there a quote of his statement somewhere?

FWTW, Euronews quotes him [as](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2023/10/27/orban-opposes-the-eus-50-billion-support-plan-for-ukraine-while-fico-raises-corruption-con)

> "The Commission wants more money so that they can give it to the integration (of migrants) policy and to the Ukrainians," Orbán said upon arrival. "We do not support any of them, the professional and political arguments are lacking, we will reject them."

That's rather vague, but if/(is?) that's all he said...

Comment: Not saying he has no reason to do that does not mean he's excluding possibility to do that. I do things I see no reason for all the time. Reason is overrated.

Comment: https://24.hu/belfold/2023/10/27/orban-viktor-interju-kossuth-radio-percrol-percre/#orban-az-ukranok-a-fronton-nem-fognak-gyozni - is this helping?

Comment: And this - https://www.origo.hu/itthon/20231027-orban-viktor-valtozas-kell-brusszelben.html ; and this one - https://www.origo.hu/itthon/20231027-orban-viktor-valtozas-kell-brusszelben.html ; Also Orban had met with Putin and Xi in China on the 1B1R summit.

Comment: His stand has been that he isn't in favour of sending aid to support the war (which is understandable as he wants an amicable relationship with Russia). He hasn't (so far) objected to aid for relief.